# Trouble with python files

Tags: python

The problem is that the code wont except the correct password, I can't seem to get it working correctly and have been trying for a while. I have tried many ways in which I would have though the code may have worked but so far none.

code:

```
import os

PassCount = 0
SetUp = 0

newpath = r"PassEncryptPY"
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)

if not os.path.exists("PassEncryptPY/PassEncryptPY_PTF.txt"):
    with open("PassEncryptPY/PassEncryptPY_PTF.txt", "x"): pass

if not os.path.exists("PassEncryptPY/PassEncryptPY_ETF.txt"):
    with open("PassEncryptPY/PassEncryptPY_ETF.txt", "x"): pass

f = open("PassEncryptPY/PassEncryptPY_PTF.txt", "r+")
g = open("PassEncryptPY/PassEncryptPY_ETF.txt", "r+")


if os.path.getsize(r"PassEncryptPY/PassEncryptPY_PTF.txt") == 0:
   print("we have detected that you dont have a password")
   pas = input("Your password: ")
   f.write(pas)
   SetUp = SetUp + 1

if os.path.getsize(r"PassEncryptPY/PassEncryptPY_ETF.txt") == 0:
   print("we have detected that you dont have a email")
   ema = input("Your email: ")
   g.write(ema)
   SetUp = SetUp + 1

if SetUp != 0:
   print("Set Up complete, restarting")
   f.flush()
   g.flush()
   os.fsync(f.fileno())
   os.fsync(g.fileno())
   #f.close()
   #g.close()
   #import sys
   #os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, * sys.argv)

def Main():
   if PassCount < 3:
       inptpass = input("Please insert your password: ")
       if inptpass == f.read():
           print("test done") 
       else:
           print("nope")

Main()
f.close()
g.close()
```

output:

```
we have detected that you dont have a password
Your password: Pas
we have detected that you dont have a email
Your email: Ema
Set Up complete, restarting
Please insert your password: Pas
nope
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have to rewind the file after writing. Without that reading continues from the same place, which is after the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `f.seek(0)` in your `Main()` function to reset the cursor at the beginning of the file.

```
def Main():
   if PassCount < 3:
       f.seek(0)
       inptpass = input("Please insert your password: ")
       if inptpass == f.read():
           print("test done")
       else:
           print("nope")
```

When you are using either `read()` or `write()` function (which you do outside of the `Main()` when the password and email are not stored in files) the `read()` or `write()` will leave the cursor at the end of the file. Hence the second time you will try to read data from the file, the cursor will be at the end of the file.

Another option is to close the file and reopen it.

**Proof using `read()`:**

```
def Main():
   if PassCount < 3:
       inptpass = input("Please insert your password: ")
       print(f.read())
       print(f.read())
       f.seek(0)
       print(f.read())
       if inptpass == f.read():
           print("test done")
       else:
           print("nope")
```

Here is the output:

```
Please insert your password: 123
123

123
nope
```

Comment: I think you mean: *"When you are using the `write()` function..."*.

Comment: @bnaecker Fixed. Thank you!